# How can I disable the vim plugim snipMate to some kind of files?

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

My questions is self-explanatory, How can I disable vim snipmate to perl files for example?? I found myself frustating because its stuck with my omni-completion and neocomplcache. I just use snipMate in html files.

This same question could be asked like: How can I enable snipmate for just one type of file (html)?

Comment: It's a pity that the author didn't make this to be configurable :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move the `snipMate.vim` file from `$VIM/plugin` to another directory that is not autoloaded, like `$VIM/extra`.

Then in your .vimrc, add a line to use snipmate for HTML only:

```
autocmd FileType html,xhtml source $VIM/extra/snipMate.vim
```

Another uglier method would be to simply remove or rename all the snippets files in `$VIM/snippets` except for `html.snippets`, or a subset of those you would like to keep.  This would be more effective though if you only wanted to remove some (like only disabling perl, for example) than to disable all but one type.